# Command button to move cell value to another cell, without cell error =#REF

Tags: excel, vba, button

**Hello Everyone!**

I'm working on an excel 2007 project for my work. I'm trying to build a command button to move one cell to another cell.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
  Select Case MsgBox(Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbQuestion, Prompt:="Are you sure? ")
    Case vbYes
      Range("A2").Cut Range("B2")
    Case vbNo
  End Select
  ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123"
  ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub
```

*This is my current VBA code for cut & paste from one cell to another cell.*

But now I'm having another issue every time I press the command button. Please help me to solve this issue.

[image: screenshot]

*This is the default view of my project. In the cell, A2 has a SUM of range A4:A8 & the cell D2 is =A2, E2 is =B2*

The Problem is after clicking on the button:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, `D2` is supposed to be `=A2` now changed to `=B2 & E2` supposed to be `=B2` but now `=#REF!` error.

I could not find any solution for this issue, So please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: This is normal (expected) Excel behavior. Instead of `Range("A2").Cut Range("B2")`, try `Range("B2").Value = Range("A2").Value: Range("A2").ClearContents`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now all is working fine. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This Is the VBA Code for 2 Command Buttons:**

- I have made the second button fro reset the 1st command

.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
  Select Case MsgBox(Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbQuestion, Prompt:="Are you sure? ")
    Case vbYes
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
        Range("A2").Copy Range("B2")
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
        Range("A2").ClearContents
    Case vbNo
  End Select
  ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123"
  ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
  Select Case MsgBox(Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbQuestion, Prompt:="Are you sure? ")
    Case vbYes
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
        Range("B2").ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
        Range("A2").Value = Application.Sum(Range("$AV$45,$AX$45,$AZ$45"))
    Case vbNo
  End Select
  ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123"
  ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub
```

Thank you all for helping me out. If I missed something on this code please let me know. Thakns.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the SUM formula in B2 and not just the value, you could use this instead:

```
Range("A2").Copy Range("B2")
Range("A2").ClearContents
```

Also update the formula to use $

`=SUM($A$4:$A$8)`